# When exactly are peers saved in peers.dat file?

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers

I had tried few things when reviewed this PR: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22013

While reviewing PR https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22651, I was expecting 1 peer to be saved in peers.dat using the below steps:

1. Run Node 1:

```
bitcoind -port=18333 -rpcport=18222 -datadir="/home/user/node1" -regtest=1 -listen=1 -server=1 -debug=net -rpcuser=user1 -rpcpassword=password1 -torcontrol='127.0.0.1:9051' -proxy='127.0.0.1:9050' -onlynet=onion
```

2. Run Node 2:

```
bitcoind -port=18777 -rpcport=18666 -datadir="/home/user/node2" -regtest=1 -listen=1 -server=1 -debug=net -rpcuser=user2 -rpcpassword=password2 -addnode='127.0.0.1:18333' -torcontrol='127.0.0.1:9051' -proxy='127.0.0.1:9050' -onlynet=onion
```

3. Stop Node 1 and 2:

```
bitcoin-cli -rpcport=18222 -rpcuser=user1 -rpcpassword=password1 stop
bitcoin-cli -rpcport=18666 -rpcuser=user2 -rpcpassword=password2 stop
```

4. Restart Node 2 with different config (`onlynet=i2p` and no `proxy`):

```
bitcoind -port=18777 -rpcport=18666 -datadir="/home/user/node2" -regtest=1 -listen=1 -server=1 -debug=net -rpcuser=user2 -rpcpassword=password2 -i2psam=127.0.0.1:7656 -onlynet=i2p
```

But nothing was saved in peers.dat according to logs. So I had to use `addpeeraddress` for the test which I guess does the same thing. So if node 1 is added as outbound connection in node 2, shouldn't this be saved in peers.dat? How does it work in case of testnet or mainnet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin Core has two mostly-separate mechanisms for creating outbound connections:

- The **manual** mechanism, controlled by configuration settings `addnode`, `connect`, and the `addnode` RPC to change the addnode list at runtime. It can be used by the user to directly establish connections to peers of their choice, including ones on IP addresses that aren't publicly reachable (incl. localhost and your local network).
- The **automatic** mechanism, where Bitcoin Core maintains a database of *publicly* reachable IP addresses of peers. This database is fed by seed nodes, by what its peers rumor, and by the `addpeeraddress` RPC. This database is large (can contain several 100000s of IP addresses), and used to establish a small (8-10) number of random connections. It is also used to answer queries by other peers (the `getaddr` protocol message). This database is saved to disk every 15 minutes, in the file `peers.dat`.

The `connect` configuration option (or `-connect` command line) enables the manual connection mechanism, and disables the automatic one. The `addnode` option enables the manual one, while leaving the automatic one intact (they both have independent maximum connection counts). The `seednode` option creates a *manual* connection to a certain node, asks it for peer IPs, feeds those into the *automatic* address database, and then disconnects.

So what is happening here is that you're using `-addnode` to establish a manual connection. That peer IP does not end up in `peers.dat`, because that file belongs to the automatic connection system. It also wouldn't work: the 127.0.0.1 address is not a public one that could even be rumored to other peers - they wouldn't be able to connect to it.